# Bash extracting multiple values

Tags: bash, awk, snmp

I'm working on extracting data from SNMP services. The output looks like this.

```
experimental.94.4.5.1.6.16.0.0.192.221.13.147.179.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.1 = Hex-STRING: 00 00 00 1A 85 95 13 F4
experimental.94.4.5.1.6.16.0.0.192.221.13.147.179.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.24 = Hex-STRING: 00 00 10 8E 0C F4 99 1C 
experimental.94.4.5.1.6.16.0.0.192.221.31.68.71.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.10 = Hex-STRING: 00 00 17 10 45 A5 13 3C
```

I would like the output to be in three parts.

```
192.221.13.147.179 1 0000001A859513F4
192.221.13.147.179 24 0000108E0CF4991C
192.221.31.68.71 10 0000171045A5133C
```

I can accomplish all 3 individually using awk but not all at once.

```
awk '{print substr($0,28,35)}'
```

Comment: Show how you do each of the three parts as 3 separate `awk` commands.  Then know that `substr` returns a string which you could assign to a variable, so you could use it 3 times for 3 variables, and then print the three variables in one print statement.  You might do best splitting the fields on blanks and dots, and then selecting and printing the bits you need.  SNMP notations are enough to drive anyone dotty! Also, the command you show produces output like '`0.0.192.221.13.147.179.0.0.0.0.0.0.`' which does not correspond very closely to what you say you want produced. Lacking verisimilitude.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS="[.: ]"}{print $10"."$11"."$12"."$13"."$14" "$23" "$27$28$29$30$31$32$33$34}'
```